# Is there a mistake in the answer key in class 8 SOF IMO?

Tags: logic

In the SOF IMO conducted for class 8 this year, there is a mistake in the answer key. The question was :

**How many such pairs of letters are there in the word ORIGINAL each of which has the same number of letters between them as in the English alphabet?**

A.  One
B.  Two
C.  Three
D.  More than three

The [answer key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MGGk.png) states that the answer is D(Question no. 12) but that makes no sense. There is only one pair of alphabet with a gap between the word and the alphabet, which is I and L. So, the answer has to be one. I don't get the point why is it mentioned D, am I wrong or is the answer key wrong?

I did try asking Google Bard but it kept going back and forth with its answers of 1, 2 and 4 such pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letters don't have to follow the alphabetical order. For example, $N$ and $R$ has three letters in between them, same as $OPQ$ (although they are in the wrong order). Another example is $L$ and $R$, with $MNOPQ$.

Along with the last $I$ and $L$ (which you said), and $L$ and $N$, there are $4$ such pairs.

The main takeaway from this is that the question states **between**, and **between** doesn't care about order. For example, there are both $5$ integers in between $6$ and $1$, as well as $1$ and $6$ (the order of which the numbers go doesn't matter).

P.S. You could ask bard next time for the specific pairs, which will provide you with more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aaa Lol_dude.

Comment: you're welcome!